# JQuery Flip Switch (slider), how to check value 'on' or 'off'

Tags: jquery, slider

I've used the Flip Switch slider from jQuery to choose between 2 options: forest or road.

How can I determine in jQuery code what the current value is where the slider is on ('on' or 'off')?

This is what I have so far:

```
<img src="images/tree.png" width="15%" />
<select name="flip-1" id="flip-1" data-role="slider">
  <option value="off">Forest</option>
  <option value="on">Road</option>
</select>
<img src="images/road.png" width="15%" />

<script>
  $(window).on('load', function () { 
    alert($('#flip-1').val()); 
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the job

```
$('#flip-1').on('change',function(){
  alert($('#flip-1').val()); 
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/uFkmu/)**

Comment: thanks, I've used $('#flip-1').change(function(){}) at first but then the alert($('#flip-1').val()); didn't work for some reason and now it does :-)!

Comment: .change() would be the old way to go, but since the newer versions of jquery it's better to use .on() for binding such events to a function